# Android : In App Purchase

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am aware of in app purchase in Android and following Dungeons application for that, but I have some doubts which I want to clear.

1. Do we need to create our own custom shopping cart for the user, or do we need to display only the list of in app products with their details and give a provision to the user to select out of them, and then Google checkout will do rest and finish checkout?

   On [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/billing/index.html), I found:

   > When you use the in-app billing service to sell an item, whether it's
   >   an in-app product or a subscription, Google Play handles all checkout
   >   details so your application never has to directly process any
   >   financial transactions. Google Play uses the same checkout backend
   >   service as is used for application purchases, so your users experience
   >   a consistent and familiar purchase flow.

   Does this mean that we can't add a shopping cart for our application?
2. Is there a limit that an application can have only that specific number of in app product ids? Is there a maximum limit of product ids?
3. If a product is discontinued from my application, is there a provision to remove that product or at least prevent it from being displayed to the user?
4. In my application, there will be individual products as well as product packages. For example: a product can be a song and a package can be 4 songs together. In this case, will the package be treated as a product only at Google Play or something else? I mean, will the package of products be treated as an individual product only?

I want expert guidance and clarity on the above mentioned points. Any links of tutorials/guides are appreciated along with the explanation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've implemented IAB (In-App Billing) in my game using managed items.

**1.**
You can only purchase a single product at a time through IAB. There is no way to purchase multiple items at once so there is no "cart". The work flow is: User clicks "buy" for an item then you send the request to Google Play which gives you a `PendingIntent` which you use to show the checkout where the user completes the purchase of that single item (and then you have to do a bunch more stuff with the various responses that follow, all of which is documented in the official docs). You can't make a purchase request that will show more than one item in a single checkout.

One way you could use a cart based system (assuming it's not against any kind of Google terms of service, although I can't see why it would be) might be to just sell credit in fixed amounts for making purchases in your store with. $20 store credit, $5 store credit etc (or 200 gold for $20 of whatever if you want to use your own wacky currency). Then you can make your own cart system for spending that credit via your own server.

**2.**
I'm not aware of any limit on the number of IAB items per app.

**3.**
Which items get displayed in your app is entirely down to you. There is no way to retrieve a list of your products at runtime from Google Play. You have to hardcode the products in your app or have your own server which the app can query for a list of products to display.

If you remove an IAB item from your app through the developer console and your app attempts to purchase it you will get an error in the app so you can tell the user the item is not available.

**4.**
You might have the following items setup available for purchase:

- my_app.song1
- my_app.song2
- my_app.song3
- my_app.song4
- my_app.songpacksongs1to4

my_app.songpacksongs1to4 would just represent a purchasable item in IAB, exactly the same as the other 4 items. Items in IAB are basically just named prices with descriptions and friendly names that get shown in the checkout.

If they're unmanaged they can be bought multiple times and there is no way to restore them via IAB's restore transactions because their state isn't tracked. If they are managed they can only be bought once and you can restore them via restore transactions because the IAB server keeps track of their purchase state.

There is no Google Play server side method to say that an item represents a collection of other items. The "package" is just another named price.

If you have logic you need to apply that controls whether the user can purchase a package or individual item based on the state of a different item you need to do everything yourself in your app and/or on your own server.

Comment: thanks for replying ... answered my all questions ... one more thing i want to know : Do we need to submit any legal documents for our IAB products ??

Comment: No, you just make products and off you go. No additional IAB specific requirements beyond the normal ones for selling through Google Play